# Display column on a table hash

Tags: powershell, hashtable

The date column does not appear but if you specify the name, it appears.

```
$Tableau = @()
$lignetab = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$colonnes = [ordered]@{ 'InstanceName' = 'essai';
                        'Allume' = $True;
                        'Description' = 'blabla';
                        'Version' = '1.0';
                        'Fichier Version' = $True;
                        'Fichier path' = $True;
                        'Fichier logins' = $True;
                        'Fichier linkedservers' = $True;
                        'Fichier configuration' = $True;
                        'Fichier restauration' = $True; 
                        'Date' = (Get-date);
                    }
$lignetab | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $colonnes -TypeName Asset
$Tableau += $lignetab 
$Tableau | Format-Table -AutoSize  ## COLUMN DATE NOT PRESENT !!!
$Tableau | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property 'InstanceName','Allume','Description','Version','Fichier Version','Fichier path','Fichier logins','Fichier linkedservers','Fichier configuration','Fichier restauration','Date'
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a limit to the number of columns displayed by default(10 on mine..v5)...since you are using a customtype `Asset`. you can probably create a [ps1xml format file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg580944(v=vs.85).aspx) and include all your columns in the table view.
or just reduce your hashtable by one property :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the all symbol. This will get all the object properties without the need to specify each of them.

```
$Tableau | Format-Table -Property *
```

And with AutoSize parameter:

```
$Tableau | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property *
```